# How can I send Kendo filter object to controller action

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can I send Kendo grid filter to action in ASP.NET MVC?

I'm using this construction and it's working, but I can't get sended value in controller. Parameter "model" in action is empty.

```
    $('#btn-print').click(function () {
        filter = $('#trips').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.filter();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '@Url.Action("Print", "Trips")',
            //dataType: 'json',
            data: filter,
            success: function (d) {
                var win = window.open('about:blank');
                with (win.document) {
                    open();
                    write(d);
                    close();
                }
                //alert('print click.');
            }
        })
    });
```

ASP.NET action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Print(object model)
    {
        var r = Request;
        return View();
    }
```

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is a bit suprising to me. Why not just create

```
var customDS = new kendo.data.dataSource(  
    transport: 
    {
      read: 
      {
        url: '@Url.Action("Print","Trips")',
        dataType: 'aspnetmvc-ajax'
      }
    },
  requestEnd: function (d) {
                var win = window.open('about:blank');
                with (win.document) {
                    open();
                    write(d);
                    close();
                }
});)
```

and simply copy the filters?

```
if ($('#trips').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.filter())
{
   // if no filters are applied .filter() might return undefined, so to prevent
   // errors lets check if any filters are applied
   var filters = $('#trips').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.filter().filters;
   customDS.filter(filters);
}
```

Then proceed as you're proceeding with the trips grid.
Please note that dataType is not json.

However, if you absolutely have to do it without using dataSource and as json, then its going to be a lot harder. `dataSource.filter()` 
returns object composed of 'filters' array and 'logic'. Each element in filters is object composed of 'field', 'value' and 'operator'. At the moment your parameter 'model' is empty is simply because you're not sending anything defined by the name 'model'. In reality your data looks like this:

```
data: { filters: [somearray], logic: 'somelogic' }
```

If you want to pass it as json, your parameters in the controller should reflect what are you really sending (or you could bind prefix) so that deserialization could do its magic. 
So its either

```
data: {model : filter}
```

or

```
 public ActionResult Print(Filters filters, string logic)
```

Where Filters is a class that has 3 field, the same as client-side `dataSource.filter().filters` array.
And because one of the fields is 'operator', which is AFAIR C# restricted keyword, you'd also have to move all the data from 'filters' to some 'temporaryFilters: {field:'', value:'', _operator:''}. Which is far too much work, so give up on that solution and use the dataSource one :)

Comment: Hello, thank you for so extensive reply; but what I really want to do is show PDF with actually filtered grid... :) And if I understand well, you write something like: after data load open pop-up window and display response. I want to do something like this: user shows grid, filters data and then print current data what he/she see. So, it's a reason why I want send current filter. And yes, I have to create Strongly typed class for Filter. Btw: "operator" is key word, but you can use @operator.

Comment: And it's helpfull add property "type" as string - I want to know what type of value I'm using, because I want create "where" condition in linq query. :)

Comment: The dataSource approach suggested by me sends current grid filter to Print action in Trips controller (well, with some other stuff). BTW - thanks for the @operator, I did not know that.